# WP wp_list_authors ломается вывод на optioncount

Tags: php, wordpress

Пробую вывести всех пользователей у которых есть опубликованные посты через стандартную функцию Wordpress [wp_list_authors](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_authors) и отсортировать их по количеству этих постов.

```
<ol class="authors_list">
<?php
  $args = array(
   'orderby' => 'post_count',
   'show_fullname' => true,
   'optioncount' => true
   );
wp_list_authors($args); ?>
</ol>
```

Но вывод ломается с критической ошибкой при указании параметра `optioncount` Может кто-то подсказать что не так? *И пользователи и опубликованные посты есть.

Ошибка

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\wp-includes\author-template.php:568 Stack trace: #0 D:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\wp-content\themes\test_2022\page-author.php(15): wp_list_authors() #1 D:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('D:\\OSPanel\\doma...') #2 D:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('D:\\OSPanel\\doma...') #3 D:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\index.php(17): require('D:\\OSPanel\\doma...') #4 {main} thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\test.loc\wp-includes\author-template.php on line 568
```

Comment: Хоть бы ошибку привели :)

Comment: Привел. *Хотя, не знаю как это может помочь.

Comment: Ну например можно заглянуть в указанный файл и строку, и посмотреть что именно ломает вывод :) что за объект там не конвертируется :)

Comment: Уверен, что слово пишется либо через нижнее подчеркивание, либо через camelCase

Comment: Это первое, что было опробовано. В документации же, что в первом сообщении добавлено, разписано как сформирована данная функция. Возможно если указываеться значение `'optioncount'` необходимо обязательно ещё какое-то значение отменное от дефолтного указывать, но не понимаю какое именно.

Comment: 'echo' попробуйте добавить. У вас в ошибке указано что не может обработать объект, как раз echo и отвечает что вы передаете строки или объекты